# How to disable central Daylight time in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, windows, timezone

In almost all the Mexican territory daylight saving time has been removed, so I am having problems with an OnPremise NodeJS application and then Windows shows the following conflict: Each and every NodeJS application runs with daylight saving time.

[image]

However on the operating system Windows Server 2016, Windows 10, Edge, Chrome
Edge Console:
[image]

Windows:

[image]

I know that I can handle the data with third-party libraries or, if applicable, convert to UTC. The detail is the time it would cost me to invest, in addition to each column, records and others.

Do you know of a way to disable it?

I have tried to change the time zone however I have not been successful. Thank you

Comment: "then Windows shows the following conflict" - what conflict? Yes, you're getting different results - but that's only for the local time, which I'd expect to normally be displayed on a client. If you're storing the *server local time* then I'd say it's well worth investing in the time to stop doing that. (That doesn't mean always using UTC; it depends on the column type.)

Comment: The conflict appears when a database query is made, for example, a user inserts a record at 08:00 if I send it with UTC when converting it to local in a backend application, it looks for it at 09:00

Comment: You should decide whether the record should *actually* be in UTC or in local time. If it should be in local time, then your query should also be in local time, without the server doing any time zone conversion. If it should be in UTC, then there shouldn't be any problems anyway. (Basically, a conversion to *server* local time zone is almost always a bad idea... converting to the *user's* local time zone is fine, but that's usually best done client-side.)

Comment: My Node.js version 18.14.0 shows GMT-06:00, in accordance with my Windows OS. What Node.js version do you use?